# Multiple classname selectors with SASS

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I have a CSS code that needs to be converted to SASS to make more versatile and easy to edit.

That I need to achieve is the following: I have this selector:

```
.responsive .selector,
.responsive-no-touch .selector,
.responsive-android .selector {
     property: value;
}
```

How can I make a mixin to target `.responsive`, `.responsive-no-touch` and `.responsive-android` and I only need to write the `.selector` part?

This doesn't work:

```
.responsive, 
.responsive-no-touch, 
.responsive-android {
    .selector {
         property: value;
    }
}
```

I'm using Liferay and this platform compiles CSS with SASS automatically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example, for this kind if markup:

```
<div class='responsive'>
    <div class='selector'></div>
</div>
```

But as I understood you have something like that:

```
<div class='responsive selector'>
</div>
```

That's why you should use:

```
.responsive, 
.responsive-no-touch, 
.responsive-android {
    &.selector {
         property: value;
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, I think you are right. I missed the parent selector `&`. Sorry I'm new in SASS. I will try and I tell you.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude take a look, to [this](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) part of SASS documentation

Comment: Thank you. I read that kind of things in the past, but I was stucked and my brain was collapsed, that's because I ask the question. I will accept this answer as correct because it's not the first, but there are an explanation and you have less upvotes than the other answer. Both of you are meritory of the reputation growing.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the below?

```
.responsive, 
.responsive-no-touch, 
.responsive-android {
    &.selector {
         property: value;
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, I think you are right. I missed the parent selector &. Sorry I'm new in SASS. I will try and I tell you.